# Does WiX support .NET core?

Tags: .net-core, wix

WiX v3.11.2 does not support .NET Core. WiX v4 look it will support .NET Core however it's in development phase and no updates on release dates. We want to call a Custom actions developed in .NET Core from WiX.

Note: No wrapper class developed in .NET Framework will be allowed to call custom action.

Comment: Why do you want to develop .NET core custom actions?

Comment: Because we re-use the application business logic for custom actions. Application is developed in .NET Core. This will help us for ease of maintenance and don't need .NET Framework installed in the target machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the business logic in .NET standard libraries and then call it from .NET Framework custom actions and .NET core applications.   Any modern version of Windows is going to have .NET Framework already installed.

Your MSI isn't running anywhere else.